# Time components of numdifftools.Jacobian should not be equal to zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, ode, solver

I am solving differential equations numerically using `solve_ivp` in order to integrate positions and velocities from an initial condition. This is straighfoward in Python and easy to do. But I am also calculating the partials of final positions and velocities with respect to the initial positions/velocities and time using `numdifftools.Jacobian`. This I have more trouble mastering. Let me explain.

I have a set of differential equations (see `rhs_CR3BP` function) that I numerically integrate over a timespan `[0,T]` using the Python solver `solve_ivp` given an initial state vector `X_0` at t=0 (position and velocity). At the end of the integration, I have all the state vectors from t=0 to t=T stored in `solve_ivp.y`, with the final state vector `X_f` at t=T stored in `solve_ivp.y[:, -1]`.

I am trying to compute numerically partial derivatives of the final state vector `X_f` with respect to the initial state vector `X_0` and period `T`, which are in fact the components of a Jacobian matrix.

Consider the following vector:

```
X = [x_0, y_0, z_0, vx_0, vy_0, vz_0, T] # this is X_0 and T
```

The vectorial partial derivative of `X_f` relative to `X` is given by the following Jacobian matrix:

[image]

To compute this matrix, I made a function (see `propagation` function) that takes as a variable a vector composed of `X_0` and `T` called `X`, and returns `X_f`. Then, this function is combined with `numdifftools.Jacobian` to compute the Jacobian matrix. When I run my code (see below), the Jacobian matrix is properly calculated for the partial derivatives of `X_f` relative to `X_0` (first 6 columns), but the very last column with partial derivatives of `X_f` relative to `T` are equal to zero. I know this cannot be because those derivatives are actually the final velocities and accelerations at t=T.

[image]

How come the initial condition `X_0` is taken into account in the evolution of `X_f` and the time `T` is not? That does not make any sense. In `solve_ivp`, it looks as if the timespan (`tspan=(0,T)`) is completely ignored but the initial condition (`y0=X_0`) is not. Why is that? Am I not using `solve_ivp` and `numdifftools.Jacobian` properly?

If my question needs more details, please let me know, I'll happily provide more explanations by the end of day.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numdifftools as nd

def rhs_CR3BP(t, X0, mu):
    """Integrates the CR3BP equations of motion"""
    
    x, y, z, v_x, v_y, v_z = X0
    
    r = np.sqrt((x-1+mu)**2+y**2+z**2)
    d = np.sqrt((x+mu)**2+y**2+z**2)
    
    a_x = 2*v_y + x - (1-mu)*(x+mu)/d**3 - mu/r**3*(x-1+mu)
    a_y = -2*v_x + y - (1-mu)*y/d**3 - mu*y/r**3
    a_z = -(1-mu)*z/d**3 - mu*z/r**3
    
    return np.array([v_x, v_y, v_z, a_x, a_y, a_z])

def propagation(X, mu):
    
    X_0 = X[0:6]
    T = X[6].real
    
    sol = solve_ivp(fun=rhs_CR3BP, t_span=(0, T), y0=X_0, method='RK45', rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-10, args=(mu,), dense_output=True)
    X_f = sol.y[:, -1]
    
    return X_f

T = 0.732 # period
x, y, z, vx, vy, vz = 1.085, 0, 0, 0, -0.464, 0 # position and velocity components
X0 = [x, y, z, vx, vy, vz] # initial state vector
X = np.array([x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, T]) # X_0 and T

mu = 0.012 # arbitrary parameter
f = lambda X: propagation(X, mu)
f = nd.Jacobian(f, method='complex')
DF = np.real(f(X))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing `nd.Jacobian(f, method='complex')` with `nd.Jacobian(f, method='central')` yields the following matrix:

```
array([[ -1.809,   0.609,   0.   ,  -0.16 ,   1.148,   0.   ,   0.027],
       [ -5.119,   3.386,   0.   ,  -1.052,   1.34 ,   0.   ,   0.468],
       [  0.   ,   0.   ,  -0.849,   0.   ,   0.   ,   0.153,   0.   ],
       [-22.765,  10.802,   0.   ,  -3.568,   8.253,   0.   ,   1.907],
       [  0.836,  -0.096,   0.   ,   0.103,   0.621,   0.   ,  -0.156],
       [  0.   ,   0.   ,  -1.532,   0.   ,   0.   ,  -0.902,   0.   ]])
```

These entries for df/dT in the final column look much more plausible.

All of your variables appear to be real-valued, but you have requested `method=complex` in your call to `Jacobian`. This is asking for trouble, for reasons I shall expand on below.

#### Real-differentiable vs complex-differentiable

As stated in the numdifftools docs:

> Complex methods are usually the most accurate provided the function to differentiate is **analytic**

An analytic function is one that can be represented by a **power series**, and there is a special relationship between **analytic** functions and **complex-differentiable** functions: these two classes of functions are the same (skipping some technical details). In contrast, there are many functions that are differentiable along the real line but which are not analytic.

Importantly, just because a function is differentiable for real numbers, does not mean it is also complex-differentiable (i.e. analytic). Your function is guaranteed to be real-differentiable with respect to `T`, but there is no guarantee that it will be complex-differentiable for complex `T`.

Complex-differentiable functions are a much more select group than real-differentiable functions, and they have many properties that are not true of all real-differentiable functions (besides being analytic). For example, if a complex function can be differentiated once, it can be differentiated infinitely many times. An example of a real-differentiable function that is not complex-differentiable is `f(x) = |x|**3`.

Comment: I was actually able to make it work using the complex step differentiation method for this example in Matlab using `ode45`. It seems that the issue here is with `solve_ivp`. I did a little bit of digging and noticed that `solve_ivp` cannot work with a complex `T` by design. See `scipy\integrate_ivp\ivp.py`, at line 508: `t0, tf = float(t_span[0]), float(t_span[1])`. I don't know how to change that or if could use another solver in Python that would do the job. Do you have any suggestions?